# Getting error when running rake tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm unable to run Rake tasks in my Ruby on Rails app. I tried different solutions online but always ended with the same error. Cannot find a solution for this issues. I updated the gems as described in some solutions like update rspec-rails or else. However, I'm still struggling to find a solution for it.

Below my issue:

```
vagrant@weblinc-development:~/tahariasl$ bundle show rspec
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-3.2.0
vagrant@weblinc-development:~/tahariasl$ bundle exec rake db:drop
W, [2018-03-19T19:57:14.973894 #28261]  WARN -- sentry: ** [Raven] Unable to load raven/integrations/rack-timeout: uninitialized constant Rack::Timeout::RequestTimeoutException
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
[DEPRECATION] `last_comment` is deprecated.  Please use `last_description` instead.
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.6/lib/action_dispatch/http/mime_type.rb:163: warning: previous definition of PDF was here
rake aborted!
Weblinc::Decorator::InvalidDecorator:
Problem:
  To allow decorating modules, this method can only be used to
  decorate constants in the `Weblinc` namespace.
Summary:
  To ensure decoration of modules will occur for any objects
  which have already included that module, we track module
  subclasses in the `Weblinc` namespace. Therefore, we cannot
  guarantee module decoration will work for constants outside
  the `Weblinc` namespace.
Resolution:
  Use `class_eval`, `module_eval`, `prepend` or the like to
  acheive the decoration you want.
/home/vagrant/tahariasl/app/decorators/models/weblinc/payment/processing_decorator.rb:2:in `<module:Weblinc>'
/home/vagrant/tahariasl/app/decorators/models/weblinc/payment/processing_decorator.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/tahariasl/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:drop => db:mongoid:drop => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: Hi, so what have you tried with `/home/vagrant/tahariasl/app/decorators/models/weblinc/payment/processing_decorator.rb` to fix the error that is being reported?

Comment: Can you be specific, please?  I don't know what to fix or to do to make it work. If you can be specific about it will be nice. Do you need to see the code for that file? I don't have this file inside my app at all.

Comment: yes I can't be specific because I can't debug a file based on the name of the file ;) The error is saying that that is the location of the bug... it claims to be located in `app/decorators/models/weblinc/payment/processing_decorator.rb`
You say it isn't in your app... but that looks like an app file-location to me... if it's not in your app, where is that?